# Bug with the Low Quality Posts Recommend Deletion dialog box with the new top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, low-quality-posts, top-bar

I just got to see the new top bar when I was reviewing low quality posts. The problem is that when I click Recommend Deletion in the Low Quality Posts queue, the top of the dialog is hidden under the top bar:

[image]

Can we fix this bug please?

I suggest making the text in the Recommend Deletion dialog smaller to make the dialog itself smaller also so that the Delete button is available without scrolling. I hate having to scroll down every time I want to click Delete.

Comment: should be fixed in upcoming build.

Comment: @Paweł It's fixed now, you can tag it [status-completed].