# New navigation bar hides part of another window

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

I clicked "close" on a question I had already voted to close.  Here's what the screen looks like:
[image: screenshot]

The box which shows the close options is partly hidden.  I can see the bottom tips of some lower-case descenders peeking out.  Also, I think there's a "close" button hidden under the nav bar.

Comment: Related: [Bug with the Low Quality Posts Recommend Deletion dialog box with the new top bar](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343731/2675154)

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343325/1663001 (which has been [marked as deferred](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/343325/revisions))

Comment: this was an issue on short questions displayed on smaller screens.. It should be fixed in next build.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been reported [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343325#343325) and I tagged it as [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred). But, to be honest, I have to apologize, because I initially misunderstood what the real problem was.

As I mentioned in comment above, this was an issue on short questions displayed on smaller screens. We make some math calculations in JavaScript in order to position this popup. So sometimes its initial position was below header. This was the main problem and it is now fixed.

Nevertheless, I still think that our `.popup`s need some love and they are far away from being perfect & bulletproof. I wanna work on them but this is simply not our priority right now.