# Close question modal can be dragged off screen

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, close-dialog

I often drag the close modal out of the way to check something in the question or a comment, and noticed recently that sometimes I'm dragging it so the top of the modal is under the nav bar. Indeed, I can drag it well out of the browser's viewport – I noticed this recently in regards to the new top bar, but I'm not sure if it was always possible to drag off screen.

Dragging offscreen is not a problem in itself, but when the draggable area is offscreen, I'm no longer able to drag the box back!

The dragging of the close/flag modal's top bar should be limited to the viewport, and z-index should also be increased so the modal is always above the top-nav bar.

[image: Screenshot showing close modal dragged mostly off screen]

Comment: BTW this is not a duplicate of a [similar question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343849/1255289) which relates to the default placement of the close modal, not its behaviour when being dragged.

Comment: I think it should be allowed to be dragged out of the viewport *within reason* as I may want to review the question without closing the dialog and if it were restricted to the window, then I'd have to fight with it.  But keeping at least a portion of the window within view (so that it can be retrieved) would be good.  (The number of times I've dragged subwindows of programs below my taskbar....I would be a rich man at only a nickle).

Comment: Yeah I guess I didn't mention it up there but the real problem comes when I try to move it back! Will update